# on-hold also firing ng-click on Samsung phones

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two functions `openMenu()` and `openItem()`
* If i click on item it will activate ng-click with `openItem()`
* If i hold, it will trigger on-hold with `openMenu()` calling `$ionicActionSheet.show({.....});`

It works fine on Motorola and Asus devices, but **Samsung** is firing twice.
Is it opening the menu and opening the item (causing the change of the view and closing menu at once)

Any solutions?

PS:

- I'm using Ionic Framework
- I have discovered something.. If you hold and stay with your finger in the same point before move up yout finger, it will occurs, BUT.. if you do a litte swipe (move to any side, just 1mm movement) it will not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution.i code as bellow.

```
<div ng-repeat="array in location.location track by $id($index)">
   <div on-hold="array.qty = 0;array.showInput=true" on-release="array.showInput=false">
     <label ng-show="!showDisabled(array.showInput)" ng-bind="array.qty" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();$event.stopPropagation();array.qty = array.qty + 1;></label>
     <label ng-show="showDisabled(array.showInput)" ng-bind="array.qty"></label> 
  </div>
</div>
```

if i directly write ng-show="array.showIput" AND ng-show="!array.showIput" then ng-click fire after on-hold.

So i took two label one show after on-hold, without click-able label the other label  with click-able and show it using the function. Then function is

```
$scope.showDisabled = function(val){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(val){return true;}
        else{return false;}
    });
  }
```